# How to optimize drawing in an array

Tags: c++

I'm having a small problem optimizing this code.
it draws a sprite from a 1D array to a screen, also a 1D array.
Basically, I want to write in the pixData array the value of array.
However, both arrays have different widths, so just a memset to copy data in the asset wouldn't be enough, as it would result in the sprite not lining up correctly.
Any suggestion is more than welcome, thanks !

```
void PlaceSprite(uint8_t* array, Transform* trans)
    {
        tempX = 0;
        tempY = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < trans->sizeY * trans->sizeX * 4; i += 4)
        {
            tempX++;
            if (tempX >= trans->sizeX)
            {
                tempX = 0;
                tempY++;
            }
            if (array[i + 3] == 0 || trans->posX + tempX < 0 || trans->posX + tempX >= x) { continue; }
            arrayPosCheck = (4 * x) * (trans->posY + tempY) + 4 * (trans->posX + tempX);
            pixData[arrayPosCheck] = array[i];
            pixData[arrayPosCheck + 1] = array[i + 1];
            pixData[arrayPosCheck + 2] = array[i + 2];
        }
    }
```

To help a bit, array[i+3] is the alpha channel for one pixel with red = i, green = i+1, blue = i+2

Comment: Use memcpy once for each horizontal line. Calculate the offset in the sprite array and the offset in the screen array, `((curY*imgWidth + curX)*4)` (where imgWidth is the sprite or screen width, while curX will be 0 for the sprite and the x position of the target image on the screen) then just copy `sprite-width * 4` bytes.

Comment: @enhzflep How would I then deal with removing the alpha however ? the if(a=0){continue} is important, as I'm writing a bunch of stuff to the same screen Array, sometimes overlapping. is there a way to tell it to skip certain values when using memcpy ?

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution, following @enhzflep idea. Basically, I start by a while to obtain the longest uncut by alpha, by end of line, or by the border of the screen, and do a memcpy on it ! And I repeat that for every line :) Increased framerate significantly.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).